# Page curl animation on UIcollectionViewCell ios

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionviewcell, page-curl

I am using `UICollectionView` to display images. Now I have to Display images in `page-curl` animation. How can I show `page-curl` animation on `UIcollectionViewCell` instead of `scrolling`?

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see this once it helps you http://www.iostute.com/2015/04/how-to-implement-partial-and-full-page.html

Comment: Yes I have used this code..But how can I implement on cell when user move from one index to another.

Comment: implemnt your code in willDisplayCell surely works

Comment: but it shows scrolling also

Comment: You can use UIPageController for page curl Animation. That is easy and you only need to add your views in the controller.

Comment: But In UIpageController, how can I add views dynamically?

Comment: I'm also facing this same problem, Have you found any resources regarding your question????